# Can't use Tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, server, tomcat8

I have installed Tomcat v8.0.35 and I have configured it following these steps ([here](http://doraprojects.net/blog/?p=1109)). I have checked it and it's working fine: I went to localhost:(myport) and got this[image]

Now I installed Eclipse Mars2 Enterprise Edition, New->Dynamic Web Project, I had no target runtime so New Runtime->Tomcat v8->gave the installation folder->finish. Now the project has been created but when I click the server tab, it doesnt show tomcat. I get this message "No servers available. Click this link to create a server" but I can't create a server using tomcat8.

The server is on when I create my eclipse project

I don't know exactly how to show the file so I will just ctrl+c, ctrl+v (sorry in advance).

So the warnings and errors from the .log file looks like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-05-18 13:50:56.781
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Bogdan'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1 0 2016-05-18 13:53:41.383
!MESSAGE cacheFile=file:/E:/EclipseMars/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery/serverAdapterSitesDetails.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1 0 2016-05-18 13:53:41.406
!MESSAGE cacheFile=file:/E:/EclipseMars/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery/serverAdapterSitesDetails.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2016-05-18 13:53:48.551
!MESSAGE Invalid site reference %updateSiteURL in feature com.pramati.eclipse.feature.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2016-05-18 13:53:48.572
!MESSAGE Invalid site reference %updateSiteURL in feature com.pramati.eclipse.feature.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2016-05-18 13:53:48.576
!MESSAGE Invalid site reference %updateSiteURL in feature com.pramati.eclipse.feature.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2016-05-18 13:54:09.340
!MESSAGE Connection to http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sapnweclipse/updates/features/com.sap.netweaver.porta.ide.eclipse.feature_0.4.1.200907211842.jar failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2016-05-18 13:54:46.964
!MESSAGE Connection to http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sapnweclipse/updates/features/com.sap.netweaver.porta.ide.eclipse.feature_0.6.3.201004231243.jar failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1 0 2016-05-18 13:55:02.643
!MESSAGE cacheFile=file:/E:/EclipseMars/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery/serverAdapterSitesDetails.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1 0 2016-05-18 13:55:16.978
!MESSAGE cacheFile=file:/E:/EclipseMars/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery/serverAdapterSitesDetails.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1 0 2016-05-18 13:59:26.787
!MESSAGE cacheFile=file:/E:/EclipseMars/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery/serverAdapterSitesDetails.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-05-18 14:02:58.149
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.performFinish(TaskWizard.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.showNewRuntimeWizard(ServerUIPlugin.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServerUIUtil.showNewRuntimeWizard(ServerUIUtil.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.launchNewRuntimeWizard(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.internalLaunchNewRuntimeWizard(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage$7.widgetSelected(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2284)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeComposite.init(TomcatRuntimeComposite.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeComposite.setRuntime(TomcatRuntimeComposite.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeWizardFragment.enter(TomcatRuntimeWizardFragment.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard$2$1.run(TaskWizard.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 61 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-05-18 14:03:16.853
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.performFinish(TaskWizard.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.showNewRuntimeWizard(ServerUIPlugin.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServerUIUtil.showNewRuntimeWizard(ServerUIUtil.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.launchNewRuntimeWizard(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.internalLaunchNewRuntimeWizard(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage$7.widgetSelected(DataModelFacetCreationWizardPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2284)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeComposite.init(TomcatRuntimeComposite.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeComposite.setRuntime(TomcatRuntimeComposite.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui.internal.TomcatRuntimeWizardFragment.enter(TomcatRuntimeWizardFragment.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard$2$1.run(TaskWizard.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 61 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 4 6 2016-05-18 14:04:16.417
!MESSAGE Saving preferences failed: reporterEmail=null ; version: 1.100.0.v20160217-0435
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.put(EclipsePreferences.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.putValue(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.di.SystemSettingsCreationFunction$1.notifyChanged(SystemSettingsCreationFunction.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.impl.UserSettingsImpl.setReporterEmail(UserSettingsImpl.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.impl.UserSettingsImpl.eSet(UserSettingsImpl.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.impl.SystemSettingsImpl.eSet(SystemSettingsImpl.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eSet(BasicEObjectImpl.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.utils.Servers.copyIfUnset(Servers.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.utils.Servers.setAsDefaults(Servers.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.dialogs.EclipseServerPage.dispose(EclipseServerPage.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.dispose(Wizard.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.hardClose(WizardDialog.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.close(WizardDialog.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.cancelPressed(WizardDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$1.widgetSelected(WizardDialog.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.handlers.OpenSystemSetupWizardHandler.execute(OpenSystemSetupWizardHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core.SystemControl.executeHandler(SystemControl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.notifications.SetupSystemNotification$1.execute(SetupSystemNotification.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.notifications.NotificationPopup$1.linkActivated(NotificationPopup.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ImageHyperlink.handleActivate(ImageHyperlink.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$2(AbstractHyperlink.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

There would have been some more lines but I exceeded the characters limit.

Edit 2[image]

Edit 3: The problem was that I downloaded the (tomcat) zip for Mac (yep, I feel so bad right now). Thanks a lot, @holidayCoder !

Comment: is there an additional error you get?

Comment: I don't think so, just the fact that eclipse "cant see" my server.

Comment: And you are not able to add a tomcat8 server into the server tab? Have a look into the workspace_folder /.metadata/.log file, is there a error printed after you've tried to add the server?

Comment: @ZeusNet Yeah, I do have some warning and error messages. I'll edit my post in a second

Comment: Can't check from the job (really old eclipse here ;) ) but I'm pretty sure that the runtime is just the "core", you need to create a server using that runtime. You should be able to add a server from the empty list.

Comment: Could you maybe clear the log and than try to add the server? The log should than be smaller and we could see if the adding results in an error

Comment: @LerulLer when you click on tomcat 8,click next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with eclipse **JUNO**

[download binaries of tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)

**steps to integrate with eclipse**

1 .Go to window>preferences>Server>runtime envirnoment>add(browse where your **extracted** tomcat binary is) click finish

2. Go to windows>show view>server
3. click on add new server >Apache>Server version and just navigate clicking ok and finish 
   You'll have your server ready

**Because sometime eclipse dosen't accepts new server from server tab directly**

Hope that helps!

Comment: still not working, at step 3, I have this message: "No servers are available. Click this link to create a server" but after I click it, I can't create a server...

Comment: click on link and just follow ok and finish

Comment: actually in preferences you provided the link now its time to integrate it to server window

Comment: I can't, there are 4 buttons: back, next, finish, cancel. Only cancel is clickable.

Comment: is it providing a browse button?

Comment: and what server u downloaded , it its tomcat 8 when u click on new server tab it navigates you to next window where click on apache > tomcat 8 i just updated answer

Comment: after I click on tomcat 8, nothing happens

Comment: when you click on tomcat 8 click next

Comment: I can't, only cancel is clickable

Comment: http://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/

Comment: and one more thing did you follow the procedure through windows>preferences to provide path to tomcat

Comment: I did, I will follow the steps from your link, hope it works

Comment: if you are installing tomcat for first time make sure you follow step 1 because either way if you install tomcat through server window , chances are it may not work (as with juno )

Comment: and please do tell me what is the result

Comment: I have installed tomcat before I go into eclipse, i don't know if that may be the problem, also I'll post a picture above.

Comment: i mean tomcat **binary** for first time

Comment: I don't think I know what tomcat binary exactly is, I went to [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) and downloaded the zip just below the "Core"

Comment: ok, in the preferences, i went to servers, runtime environment, add, clicked on apache tomcat v8, next, Name "server", path "E:\tomcat8\apache-tomcat-8.0.35" and at JRE, I choose "Workbench default JRE" or "jre1.8.0_91"?

Comment: and did you extracted it and followed the procedure i told you..its right binary and for more accuracy download ,which defines bit version ie either 64 or 32

Comment: I clicked finish, still nothing in server view and yes, i extracted it from the .rar, then I followed the steps from [here](http://doraprojects.net/blog/?p=1109)

Comment: i provided the exact steps you need to install binary ...follow them in sequence and you'll have your server ready in no time and you do not need to follow steps from that link just follow these steps carefullly 
you will have your answer

Comment: Ok, step 2 done (clicked on the blue link), step 3 done (clicked on Apache Tomcat 8) but after this, I can't click on "next" (step 4), it's just like in the picture i posted above

Comment: Ok, I'll go from start again, it must work, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112461/discussion-between-holidaycoder-and-lerul-ler).

Comment: It's working now, it was a silly mistake from me (I downloaded the Mac version of tomcat)

Comment: I thought I Did that

Answer (score 0):

[image]

your server is not properly configured. click on this link to create new server. remove all configured server and add new tomcat server.

or,

Restarting the Eclipse IDE solved the problem. or just go to ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench // folder locaiton. and deleted all the content of workbench.xmi and restarted the application. hopefully will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To add Server to project in eclipse do this steps:
1- After creating your web app
2- Right click on your project then press properties .
3- Then move Java build path
4-Then move the libraries tab
5- Press Add Library button
6- From the pop up select server runtime
7- select tomcat path. 
8- You must see it now

check and replay if it now working , we can make another work arounds

Comment: I did that, apache tomcat v8.0 appears in the list of jars and classes in libraries tab, but still, when i click the server tab, there are no servers

Comment: @LeruLer check my answer , it is sure way to install tomcat