# Eclipse - Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I run the application and build it. It doesn't show any error but when I access my application the following error comes in the console.

**Description Resource Path Location Type
Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined. MyProject Unknown Faceted Project Problem**

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Do you have Tomcat 7 in your targeted runtimes? (Project>Properties>Targeted Runtimes)

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298416/cant-use-tomcat-server-in-eclipse/37299264#37299264

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756153/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756153/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The targeted runtime version must be updated. Suppose you are using Tomcat Version 8.0 but in the targeted runtime it shows 7.0 selected.

You need to ***right click on your project > Properties > Targeted Runtime > Click the version required 8.0*** I guess. Hope it helps.

Comment: This option is not available on Eclipse Neon. Is there any workaround?

Comment: TIP for future users: in addition to this some of you might have to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172270/884674

Answer (score 6):

It might be that the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file in the .settings of your project have changed (e.g. if a colleague checks in their settings and then you pull their changes). In that case the `Project > Properties > Targeted Runtime` will be there and even checked (your original will be unchecked) but you will still have a problem.

You need to rename your runtime...

```
Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments
```

select `yours > Edit`

Change the name so that it is the same as your colleagues.

When you come to using your server that will also need to be updated...

```
double click on the server > General Information > Runtime Environment
```

use the dropdown to select the new name

Comment: Good Thanks,Actually This is problem with me.Properties > Targeted Runtime were  selected but Server > Runtime Environments  was not.

Answer (score 4):

Add your Tomcat 7 installation to your targeted runtimes.
You can do it under menu Project > Properties > Targeted Runtimes

Select your desired runtime and provide the path where it is installed.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Version:
**OXYGEN**, 2017

1. From the Project Explorer, right-click on your project > Properties > **Project Facets**
2. On the left-hand panel, click on **Runtimes** tab.
3. Select the **Runtime** (Apache Tomcat vX.0) you wish to implement.
4. Click **Apply and Close**.

You should see this specific error go away. 
Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but **Runtimes** tab cannot found. Enabling **Project Facets** the **Targete Runtime** got back in properties list.

Answer (score 1):

This error might also cause when tomcat 7.0 directory is not added in preference.You might have installed other version (ex:tomcat 8.0) and pointing 7.0 version which is not available

You can change the version in `properties` >> `project facets`

In `runtime` tab change the version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window/Preferences then Server/Runtime Environments and add the missing Runtime Environment here.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a simpler way, but installing the J2EE version of Eclipse solved this for me.  I had projects set up in an older version of Eclipse, but after upgrading to a newer, standard, version my tomcat project quit working even after installing the Web Tools Platform SDK.  So reinstalling with the J2EE version was the easiest thing that worked for me after trying several of the other solutions.