# Runtime Environment is disable on Spring Tool Suite (STS)

Tags: tomcat, runtime, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite (3.3.0).

I am trying to Configure the Apache Tomcat (6.0.45) 6.Server Runtime Environment for a Dynamic Web Project.

After I created the project, and added the Tomcat Runtime to the STS, I clicked on "Properties" and selected "Project Facets".

However the option for Apache Tomcat is disable. I have not be able to find anything in the web related to this.

How can I enable Apache Tomcat runtime on Spring Tool Suite?

[Propertied->Project Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE1WY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I found out "Dynamic Web Module 3.0" will not work with "Apache 6".
You either need to Upgrade to "Apache 8" or use "Dynamic Web Module 2.5"

If your project is already 3.0 (like this one), then you need to edit manually the project facet (STS will not allow you to change from 3.0 to 2.5).

To make the change manually follow the process below:

1. Go to your project location
2. Expand the .settings folder
3. Edit org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
4. Change version to 2.5 in this line
5. Go to STS
6. Right Click on “Your Project”
7. Refresh (F5)
8. Click on “Project” in the menu
9. Select Clean
10. Now go to the "Project Facets" screen again and you should be able to select the Apache 6 Runtime environment